# Unable to get the Read data or write data using Wagmi sh

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, react, wagmi

So here is the react code and its a simple Counter program. Deployed on the below address.

I have put both the solidity part as well as React code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract SimpleStorage{

    uint256 public counter;


    constructor() {
        counter = 0;
    }

    function increment() public {
        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    function getCounter() public view returns(uint256){
        return (counter);
    }
}
```

````
'use client'
import { useContractRead,useContractWrite } from "wagmi"
import {useAccount } from "wagmi"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const abi = `[
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "counter",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getCounter",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "increment",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]`

export default function SimpleStorage(){
    const [countervalue,setCounterValue] = useState(0)
    const {address,isConnecting,isDisconnected} = useAccount()
    console.log(address)
    const {data:CounterData} = useContractRead({
        address:"0xe8d98aaa9f03a20c06863aeb8dbdcec75641539c",
        abi:abi,
        functionName:"getCounter",
    })
    console.log(CounterData)
    const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, write } = usePrepareContractWrite({
        address: '0xe8d98aaa9f03a20c06863aeb8dbdcec75641539c',
        abi: abi,
        functionName: 'increment',
      })
    

    async function updateUIValues(){
        const counter = (await CounterData.data()).toString()
        setCounterValue(counter)
        console.log("Updated value is called !")
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(address){
            console.log(address.toString())
            updateUIValues()
        }
    },[address,isSuccess])

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1>{countervalue}</h1>
                <br></br>
                <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={async () => write()}>Increment</button> 
                {isLoading && <div>Check Wallet</div>}
                {isSuccess && <div>Transaction: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>}
                
            </div>
        </>
    )
    
}```
````

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Unable to get the Read data or write data"? Are you facing any error or what exactly? Do you expect us to study the entire code and figure out what issue you might be facing?

Comment: So, I am really not sure where the error is. but while I try to fetch the value of the get counter via the readContract it gives Undefined . Second thing is in the console repeatedly I keep getting cors error: WebSocket connection closed abnormally with code: 3000 (Authorization error: Unauthorized: invalid key).